# What does -match glob in this snippet of code do?

Tags: scripting, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm fairly new to TCL and I wanted to know what the following snippet of code does.

I searched online and couldn't find any clear explanation on it, so I hope someone can help me out with this:

```
-match glob -result {usage*}
```

To give an example of where that would fit inside the file:

```
testName{A description

} -setup{

} -body{

}-match glob -result {usage*}
```

Comment: Tcl test syntax is documented here: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/tcltest.htm

Comment: Pls. fix the formatting of your question. The tcltest-case snippet is not valid Tcl syntax at all. What were the explanations on the so-called "match mode" you have found so far? See glenn's reference.

Comment: Still, Tcl syntax remains broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular bit is a pair of options to the `tcltest::test` command. The `-result {usage*}` sets the expected result string of the test script to `usage*` (it could have been put in double quotes in this case, or even done as a bare word). The `-match glob` sets the *result matching rule* to be globbing, which is the same sort of thing you see in filename matching in the shell or in the Tcl `glob` or `string match` commands. The default matching rule is exact string equality, but in this case the test asks for the result to match if the first five characters are `usage` and the rest are unimportant (standard interpretation of the `usage*` glob pattern).

You'll need to be more careful going forward with spaces (and newlines): they're very significant in Tcl scripts as they are used to *separate* words (and commands) from each other.

---

Here's a more complete version:

```
test testName "A description" -constraints knownBug -setup {
    # Do the setting up for the test
} -body {
    # Do the things that actually produce the result
} -cleanup {
    # Tear down the things that were set up before
} -returnCodes error -match glob -result {usage*}
```

In this case, we're specifying a number of other options as well (and the first couple of arguments are obvious: a name that it's easy to search for in your test suite and a short human-readable description of what is being tested). *Not* in order, but in order that you should try to understand them in:

- `-body`: Used to specify the script that produces the result that is compared.
- `-constraints`: Used to control when to *not* run the test. Sometimes a test is known to not work for reasons that it makes no sense to report (e.g., you're running on Windows but it requires MacOS to work, or it needs to be able to reach a service that is currently down for maintenance). The constraints system is the only recommended way of skipping tests, as then you get better statistics of what is being ignored.
- `-setup`: Used to put the system into a state where it can run the test. Some tests need this, some don't.
- `-cleanup`: Used to clean up the system after the test.
- `-returnCodes`: This lets you state that you expect something other than a conventional exit of the script: an expected `error` makes the result matching be done against the error message.

I've already described `-result` and `-match` above. There's also `-output` and `-errorOutput` for handling checking of what is written to stdout and stderr respectively, but I prefer to write my tests to not use those.